# Refine Custom Function in Power Query (get Running Total with Custom Function)

Tags: powerquery, pq

I created a Custom Function to get running total with 3 variables as below.

```
(SourceTable as table, ColumnName, optional NewAddedColumnName as text) => 
    let
        Add_Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(SourceTable, "Index", 1),
        Get_RT = List.Accumulate(List.Transform(ColumnName, Number.From), {0}, (s, c) => s & {List.Last(s) + c}),
        Add_RTColumn = Table.AddColumn(Add_Index, NewAddedColumnName??"Running Total", each Get_RT{[Index]}, type number),
        Remove_Index = Table.RemoveColumns(Add_RTColumn,{"Index"})
    in
        Remove_Index

//name this AddColumn_RT
```

[image_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZW9T.png)

And this is an example with the function above.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Change_ColumnTypes = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Month", type date}}),
    GetRT_Sales = AddColumn_RT(Change_ColumnTypes, Change_ColumnTypes[Sales])  //applying the custom function here 
in
    GetRT_Sales
```

[image_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUekv.png)

You can see the code as

> *GetRT_Sales = AddColumn_RT(Change_ColumnTypes, **Change_ColumnTypes[Sales]**)*

But I want to use a code like

> *GetRT_Sales = AddColumn_RT(Change_ColumnTypes, **"Sales"**)*

I want you to retreat my function, in order to use **"Sales"** instead of **Change_ColumnTypes[Sales]** as 2nd parameter of it. **Change_ColumnTypes** written already as the 1st parameter, so don't wanna write this again.

I mean how to bring list of values in a column by text-format-variable when making custom function, or set a text-format-variable as a name of column to bring list of values in the column, whatever. very difficult with my poor English.

So, here is another question. pls advise a prefer title of this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Table.Column(SourceTable,ColumnName) in place of ColumnName

```
(SourceTable as table, ColumnName as text, optional NewAddedColumnName as text) => 
let
    Add_Index = Table.AddIndexColumn(SourceTable, "Index", 1),
    Get_RT = List.Accumulate(List.Transform(Table.Column(SourceTable,ColumnName), Number.From), {0}, (s, c) => s & {List.Last(s) + c}),
    Add_RTColumn = Table.AddColumn(Add_Index, NewAddedColumnName??"Running Total", each Get_RT{[Index]}, type number),
    Remove_Index = Table.RemoveColumns(Add_RTColumn,{"Index"})
in
    Remove_Index
```

called with

```
GetRT_Sales = AddColumn_RT(Change_ColumnTypes, "Sales")
```